# Windows: Automating the filling of a simple form in Internet explorer 8

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, browser-automation

I am trying to automate filling of a simple web form and get into the website to do some monitoring task.

The problem is that this site only works in Internet Explorer 8.
I know some coding and I have figure out a way with VBScript, but its not working and give this error

```
Z:\000-Working_on\007- SDM script\checkitv1.vbs(6, 3) Microsoft VBScript runtime
 error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'getElementsByName'
```

This used to work. Please guide me get past this window with any coding language and I will figure out and learn the language to automate the rest.

Right now my only requirements are 
1. To fill the Username and Password field with any junk.
2. Click the Submit button.

You can use any language to achieve this.

**Edit:
Here is the crude code that I tried:**

```
URL = "https://usd-gz.global.ao-srv.com/CAisd/pdmweb3.exe"
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .visible=True
        .Navigate url
        .getElementsByName("USERNAME")(0).value = "abcdef"
        .getElementsByName("USERNAME")(0).value = "daddasd0"
        '.getElementsByName("imgBtn0_button")(0).Submit
End With


  Do until ie.ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
```

Comment: This is likely going to be impossible to answer without the code of the script that is giving the error.

Comment: Ohh m sorry .. i l.ll post it in edit in a  moment(having dinner) .. its just 10 to 15 lines of crude vbscript .